# Internet explorer cannot display page but all other browsers do

Tags: internet-explorer

After upgrading to a higher version of my website it's stopped working on Internet Explorer (any version). It's only showing that Internet Explorer "cannot display the page".

The site is built on a linux server and it consists with smarty. It's displaying on all browsers except IE.

How do I debug the problem? I have plesk installed and configured. Is there anything useful in the logs?

Comment: Use the IE Developer Tools (F12) to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: I have checked but it`s not showing anything :(

Any other idea ?